# Kill a process of a user Whose username start with a particular prefix?

Tags: process, kill

I want kill specified process of all users in my ubuntu whose username sytarting with 'cs' and 'ec'

Comment: Please provide a `ps -ef | grep` with what to kill :) (give a specific keyword of the process what you want to kill)

Answer (score 1):

The processes can be killed by using the following commands.
This runs killall for all users beginning with cs or ec

```
for user in `getent passwd|cut -d: -f1|grep -E '^(cs|ec)'`;do killall -u $user;done
```

The next command goes through the process list and kills all processes of users whose name begins cs or ec

```
ps -ef|grep -E '^(cs|ec)'|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill
```

The latter is better and less resource hungry.

Comment: This will kill the users. This part in the question "kill a specific process of certain users" I read as "to kill a specific process all of these users have". So not the user but for instance all "firefox" processes of these users.

Answer (score 0):

To kill a specific process pattern for a given set of users I'd use the following command:

```
ps -aef | egrep '^(cs|ec)' | awk '{print $8}'| grep my_process_pattern | xargs pkill
```